# When using Selenium WebDriver and Ruby how do know what browser type i am using?

Tags: ruby, selenium

if there is a way to know what kind of browser is running the test?
I'm planning using it on an if statemente something like this:

```
if $driver.kind_of? Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox   
  # some code 
end
```

I have tried it with "instance_of?", "is_a?". And with some modules and classes like Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile and other.
May be I'm on the wrong track...

Comment: I probably think you can use `$driver.capabilities.browser_name == "chrome"`

Comment: It's a really bad idea to make your tests browser-specific. Also, if you're writing the test, you're choosing the WebDriver, so you *already know* what browser. You shouldn't have to test for it.

Comment: @AndrewRegan I know what you mean but in this particular case, firefox has a special behavior in some part of the test and chrome another. So I had to use an If statement for catching the two possible behaviors. And I have to taste because I define the WebDriver for Firefox, Chrome and Safari, and 3 will be tested, so in fact, I don't what the browser is without some evaluation of the web driver used in that moment. I will post the solution I get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple way of getting what browser is currently used in the test.
WebDriver was defined in this way:

```
def setup
    client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
    client.timeout = 120
    case $browserName
        when "firefox"
            $browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:firefox, :http_client => client)
        when "chrome"
            $browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:chrome, :http_client => client)
        when "safari"
            $browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:safari, :http_client => client)
        when "IE"
            $browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:internet_explorer, :http_client => client)
        else
            puts "ERROR: Wrong browser name!!"
    end

    $browser.get ""  

    $wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 30)

end
```

So with this simple statement I can get the name defined in the Webdriver:

```
browser_name = $browser.browser.to_s
```

Just simply

```
if browser_name == "firefox"
   #some code
end
```